# Find 4 points relative distances to each other, knowing several distance measurements from unknow places

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, 3d

I want to be able to localice the position of a number of elements hiden in a 3d space. I have a tool that give me the distance to every one from the point I am standing but since I cant get my own coordinates I cant use my own position as a known value.

I want to be able to create a map of where are those elements A,B,C and D

So I know where are neither the 4 points nor the places from with the distances are captured.

So There are A,B,C,and D points

and I have all the measurements I want 1,2,3,4,5...

for every measurement I know the distance from every point to my current position(unknow coordinates) You can know that what is the A point distance to every measurement for instance.

`A1,B1,C1,D1,`

`A2,B2,C2,D2,`

`A3,B3,C3,D3,`

`A4,B4,C4,D4,`

`A5,B5,C5,D5,`

...

So I want to know the distance of the points A,B,C and D to each other. Is that Posible?

As an extra help I could fix the distance from one measurment to the next (by doing periodic measurements while moving but I dont know my speed
, but not the direction unless it is straight) If this help.

To simplify the problem consider everything to be in a 2 dimension world. No other restriction

Thanks

Comment: Let be sure I understand.  For each set of measurements, do you just have $4$ distance, or do you know which is the distance to A, which is the distance to B, etc?

Comment: you know wich belong to each point

Comment: You need to add some detail to your post or it will be closed.  Most important, what are you asking?  Do you want to know the distances of A,B,C,D from one another?  Be sure to respond by **editing the question body** not with another comment.  People will vote to close based on the question, not the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, edited

Comment: Getting better, but it still needs work.  Are the 4 points in the plane, on the surface of a sphere, in three-space, or what?  What about the points from which the measurements are taken?  It would also help to know why this question is of interest.  What are you trying to do? This seems like a fairly tough question, and you need to convince someone to work on it.

Comment: I add the context thanks for your time again

Comment: If you do the periodic measurements, do you know the distance from one measurement-point to the next?

Comment: It's enough to answer the question for two points.  If you have a procedure that works for two points, you can apply it separately to each of the six pairs of points.  This may not be the most efficient way, but I'm only considering the question of possibility.  (on the other hand, perhaps a third point helps.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider for instance the first measurement you can take
$$
\left( {P_{1,\,x}  - A_{\,x} } \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {P_{1,\,y}  - A_{\,y} } \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {P_{1,\,z}  - A_{\,z} } \right)^{\,2}  = A_{\,1} ^{\,2} 
$$
you have $1$ equation in $6$ unknowns: forget for a moment that they are quadratic.

When you add the measurement taken from another point $P_2$ to $A$ you are adding 
$1$ equation and $3$ more unknowns.

Adding a measument from the same point $P_1$ to $B$
$$
\left( {P_{1,\,x}  - B_{\,x} } \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {P_{1,\,y}  - B_{\,y} } \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {P_{1,\,z}  - B_{\,z} } \right)^{\,2}  = B_{\,1} ^{\,2} 
$$
you add again $1$ equation and $3$ more unknowns.

Suppose you know that the $P_n$ are along a straight line. Then from $P_3$ onwards, the measurements 
wrt the same point $A$ will keep adding $1$ equation and $1$ unknown more :the position of $P_n$ along the line 
through $P_1,\,P_2$.

So, in any case, there will be more variables than equations.

Comment: Is it true that, as we move in a fixed direction, the sum of the squares is minimized when we are in the plane of $A,B,\text{ and } C?$  If so, we can take measurements until we land in the same plane (approximately) as $A,B,C,$ then switch to another direction to try to get on the line from A to B, then find the midpoint, etc.  I've been trying to work this out, but I'm terrible at geometry.

Comment: @saulspatz: Ah, that's a nice idea: moving according to the measurements ! it is true that, if you are in the plane $A,B,C$ and move **orthogonally** to that, the sum of sq. dist. will increase: each $d^2$ will increase by $h^2$.  As it is also true that when you reach the barycenter of $n$ points the sum of the distances will be minimum. But then .. if you can move according to measurements .. you can move to reach $0$ from $A$ and then ..

Comment: First, thanks for taking your time.
I have thought about this, with only one point it is imposible as you stated, but if you have 4 or more points for every measurement you add 4 equations and 3 variables, so you are getting one more equation than variables every time you take a measurement

Comment: I want to clarify that for every point after the first for any given measurement you are adding no unkown variables.

B postion is not know but already stated and Current position is not know but seen when creatign the first equation for A

Comment: @RaisingSpirit: sorry, I do not catch your argument.

Comment: @GCab I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying.  Do you think that moving according to measurements can be made to work, or not?  I haven't been able to make it work, but then I've always been terrible at geometry.

Comment: @saulspatz: yes, directing the movement towards diminuishing the distances will work for sure. What I am saying is that, if moving according to measurements is accepted, then you can move to diminuish the distance from A, and reach it. Then move towards B, etc.

Comment: @GCab ill expand

first Measurement 1( Measurements will be numbers)
know - distances : A1,B1,C1,D1
unknow - position: Axy,Bxy,Cxy,Dxy, 1xy

measurement 2

new info - distances: A2,B2,C2,D2
new unknow- position: 2xy

You get 4 new equations and only 2 new variables

-- A2^2 = (Ax-2x)^2 + (Ay-2y)^2 

-- B2^2 = (Bx-2x)^2 + (By-2y)^2

-- C2^2 = (Cx-2x)^2 + (Cy-2y)^2

-- D2^2 = (Dx-2x)^2 + (Dy-2y)^2